Setting up trigger using SUPERUSER on Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server
I manage a PostgreSQL database for my organisation which is set up on an Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server.
My issue is that other users need to be able to CREATE objects in the database, however when they do that they are automatically made the owner of the object, and I am not able to drop these, and unless I set up default privileges on each schema for my user, I also can't use them.
I have been looking at ways to use a trigger to reassign the object owner when it is created - https://blog.hagander.net/setting-owner-at-create-table-237/ - however I now realise that I need SUPERUSER to reassign object ownership without being the owner.
Is there any way to set up a trigger as SUPERUSER on an Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server?
I tried following - https://blog.hagander.net/setting-owner-at-create-table-237/ - however the reassign owned command did not work as I was not using superuser.

The event_trigger should work fine, the owner of the new object triggers this function and can assign the new object to a generic owner. You don't need a superuser role and you don't have it or get it either.

Like Frank Heikens said, Azure postgres does not allow the superuser role for anyone. As per Microsoft it is restricted because this will have a serious security impact.
Regarding, reassigning the owner in Azure postgres, the only way you can do it is by logging in as the owner of that object and then reassign. Nothing else will work. I too feel its a damn restricting and something has to be done.
Hope this helps.
